# How to object property parse to nested array array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

It receives data from the request body in the following format. Properly I have to insert it into the database but the format is not correct.

```
{
  name: '123',
  description: 'Dev',
  "item_variants[0]['name']": '23434',
  "item_variants[0]['quantity']": '12334',
  "item_variants[0]['unit_price']": '123123',
}
```

And how to transform the following format? Everyone's answers help me some ideas. Thank you

```
{
      name: '123',
      description: 'Dev',
      item_variants: [
         {
            name: '23434',
            quantity: '23434',
            unit_price: '23434',
         }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In express, after getting this form body you have to store this response in any variable and reformate this response after formatting you can save it into the database.

```
try {
  let inputs = req.body;

  inputs = {
    name: inputs.name,
    description: inputs.description,
    item_variants: [
      {
        name: item_variants[0].name,
        quantity: item_variants[0].quantity,
        unit_price: item_variants[0].unit_price,
      },
    ],
  };

  // NOW you can save this formatted version into the database

  const result = await Product.save(inputs);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

In item_variants name, quantity, unit_price you might change digging and getting value.

Comment: But item_variants may be multiple object arrays and I need to loop to get any data.

Comment: [@WaiPhyoNaing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17512916/wai-phyo-naing) You can do one thing you also can store this multiple array in some var after you can you with simply [0],[1],[2]  other than that we can run ForEach loop for get value